# Building access card that has an identification role

Tags: access-control, physical

The main question is should a building access card have the corporate logo on it?

In this organization, the employee ID card is separate from building access card.
We currently do not have the logo on it, nor a "drop in any mailbox" message.
All that is on it, is a photo, first, last, color-coded frame and the manufacturer's serial number of the card. The manufacturer's logo is on there, but very small with the copyright symbol.

Most people do not think the cardholder is an employee of HID.

Comment: I'm confused. The card with "photo, first, last, color-coded frame and the manufacturer's serial number" is the access card or the employee ID?

Comment: Please remember that building access cards should not be needed **within** the building.

Comment: @DeerHunter That depends. In many cases, building access cards are also used for access to more secure rooms within the building. Access to those secure rooms will only be granted to the relatively few building access cards belonging to individuals who actually need it. Regardless, I'm not really sure what bearing this would have on whether or not to include corporate identifiers on the card.

Comment: @Iszi - separate building and room access cards work better with supervised entry. Corporate logo and "drop in any mailbox" on the "external" ID card will be still useful to legit employees, while theft will not significantly increase chances of getting past the guards...

Answer (score 7):

I do not see an issue with not having a corporate logo on your access card  nor do I see an issue with not having  "*a drop in any mailbox*" message on them. The reason being that if someone loses their card, it will be impossible or very hard to find out for which building the card is used.

Also in the event someone wants to perform a targeted attack, forging a logo on a key card will be the easiest thing to do.

There are other points which are more important. For instance if someone loses a card, can you block it? Normally these cards just hold a token which is checked at the door against a list of authorized tokens.  **It is imperative that you can track all cards and block them immediately in case of theft or when someone loses them**. So when a card goes missing you need to immediately remove the token from the authorized tokens list.

I think people thinking you aren't an employee if you only have the key card isn't necessarily a bad thing if you are supposed to have two forms of id on you (employee and key card).

Comment: Also consider that building access cards are often kept alongside, and therefore likely to be lost/stolen along with, company ID cards - therefore rendering the point of whether or not there are corporate identifiers on the access card fairly moot.